# Do Bamboo Backup includes deleted plan info(config, scripts)?

Tags: bamboo

I, unfortunately, deletes the plan. How can I get that back. I tried to configure it manually but the documentation is not clear so i need it back for sure. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I you did a backup before plan removal - then start new instance of Bamboo and use that backup file during installation.